# Событие завершения функции в потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, функции

Мне нужно определить, когда функция, запущенная в отдельном потоке

```
threading.Thread(target = self.backgroundFunction, args=(..., ))
```

сама завершится, а не когда я прерву/завершу поток.

В документации нашел только про завершение потока.

Но если функция отработала раньше, чем я закрыл поток, — как «отловить» её завершение?

Comment: Вы либо можете дождаться самостоятельного завершения потока (join, гарантия выполнения кода после выполнения функции, но не обязаттельно сразу же), либо вам надо использовать собственный функционал, вызываемый в конце функции.

Comment: Не очень понятно, какого поведения вы хотите добиться. Попробуйте привести более развёрнутый пример.

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev `thread = threading.Thread(target = self.backgroundFunction, args=(..., ))` - я выделяю поток. Потом, В методе internalStop() я его прерываю `thread.join()`. Но дело в том, что функция может завершить работу раньше, чем я вызову метод internalStop(). Как мне это можно отловить? Пробовал thread.isAlive(), но он же показывает не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что не так показывает метод `is_alive`: This method returns `True` just before the `run()` method starts until just after the `run()` method terminates, т.е. он возвращает `True` тогда, когда выполняется ваша задача.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашей цели подходит метод [`is_alive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) объекта `Thread`.

> This method returns `True` just before the `run()` method starts until just after the `run()` method terminates

Мой вольный перевод: метод возвращает `True` от начала выполнения метода `run()` и до момента окончания его выполнения.

Рассмотрим на примере:

```
import time
import threading


def sleep_5_seconds():
    time.sleep(5)

t = threading.Thread(target=sleep_5_seconds)

print(t.is_alive())       # False

t.start()
print(t.is_alive())       # True
for i in range(6):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.is_alive())   # True все, кроме последних

print(t.is_alive())       # False

t.join()  # выполнится мгновенно, так как поток отработал
```

Как только метод начинает выдавать `False`, функция, запущенная в нём выполнилась.

---

**Обновление:**

Если вы хотите, чтобы после того, как выполнится функция, отработал какой-то код, вы можете просто объединить эти две функции в одну и передать это потоку на исполнение:

```
import time
import threading


def sleep_5_seconds():
    time.sleep(5)

def after_finish():
    print('Task was finished')

def aggregate():
    sleep_5_seconds()
    after_finish()

t = threading.Thread(target=aggregate)
t.start()

# через 5 секунд вы увидите сообщение в консоли => run() завершился
```

Comment: А если я не могу, как в Вашем примере в цикле дождаться завершения. Если у меня несколько функций? Где мне отлавливать .isAlive()? Я пробовал так. Но это, по сути, бессмысленно, Ведь после internalStart я могу вызвать множество функций, isAlive() изменится, но я этого не узнаю. Вот конкретный пример кода. http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=ec1d7fd74aab6a401b8946b2a9e43b33

Comment: @ИльяОльчиков Обновил ответ, может быть, это вам подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Время жизни вызова функции, переданной как `target` и потока совпадают, поэтому ничего делать не надо: `your_thread.join()` вернётся когда вызов закончится.